# Change source using VBA in excel for multiple links

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I’m new to VBA and have been tasked with creating a macro for my team to update multiple (26) external links in a single workbook. I would like to have a table of the new links and old links. The macro should match them and the new should replace the old, “change source”.

I eventually arrived at this but it takes 1 new link and replaces all old links with this single new link.

```
Sub Update_Links()
    Dim varNewLink As Variant
    Dim lnk As Variant
    
    Application.Goto Reference:="Links_Sheet"
    ' get all links
    lnk = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
    
    If Not IsEmpty(lnk) Then
        ' prompt for the new file for the link
        varNewLink = Application.GetOpenFilename("J:\Capital Production\01 2021\04 Q4 Reporting\03 Assets\08 Counterparty_Concentration\02_Counterparty\01_SH\01 Counterparty Exposure Record\Q321 Counterparty exposure record (*****) v0.2_no links.xlsm")
        ' if user didn't cancel, refresh the link
        If varNewLink <> False Then
            
            ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:=lnk(1), NewName:=varNewLink, _
                                      Type:=xlExcelLinks
            
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The code you have posted doesn't compile for multiple reasons. Can you re-add your existing code (I appreciate it doesn't work exactly as you want, but then we can advise you how to fix it if we have your actual code)

Comment: You define `lnk` with an L and use `Ink` with an I.  `lnk = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)..... ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:=Ink(1)`.  Using [Option Explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/option-explicit-statement) would point this out.

Comment: Also you're using `xlExceinks` instead of `xlExcelLinks`.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?

[image]

This code will use the table above to update the links in column A to the links in column B:

```
Sub UpdateLinks()

    Dim aLinks As Variant, vLink As Variant
    Dim rFoundLink As Range
    Dim rSrchRange As Range
    Dim MissingLinks As String
    
    'A list of your existing links that need updating.
    Set rSrchRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:A4")

    'Links that are in your workbook.
    aLinks = ThisWorkbook.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
    
    If Not IsEmpty(aLinks) Then
        For Each vLink In aLinks
            Set rFoundLink = rSrchRange.Find(vLink, , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext, False) 'Find the link in your list.
            If Not rFoundLink Is Nothing Then
                'If the link is found then update it to the link in the next column.
                ThisWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:=vLink, NewName:=rFoundLink.Offset(, 1), Type:=xlExcelLinks
            Else
                'If the link isn't found in your list then add it to a message string.
                MissingLinks = MissingLinks & vLink & vbCr
            End If
        Next
    End If

    'Any links that didn't update are displayed in a message.
    If MissingLinks <> "" Then
        MsgBox MissingLinks
    End If

End Sub
```

If you're updating all links to look at the same workbook you don't need the FIND link part:

```
Sub UpdateLinks()

    Dim aLinks As Variant, vLink As Variant

    'Links that are in your workbook.
    aLinks = ThisWorkbook.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
    
    If Not IsEmpty(aLinks) Then
        For Each vLink In aLinks
            ThisWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:=vLink, NewName:="H:\Darren Bartrup-Cook\Test\Book1.xlsm", Type:=xlExcelLinks
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: That looks great Thanks.  But i get a subscript out of range error.

Comment: how would i include the dimension

Comment: Which line gives the subscript error?  If it's the `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:A4")` line - update the worksheet name to whatever is in your file.  What do you mean by dimension?